# TypeScript, Angular 5 - nested dependencies of imported javascript modules do not resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, requirejs, angular5

I am attempting to import a javascript library into my angular5/ts application, and while I can get the library itself to load, its nested dependencies fail.

This results in functions that depend on nested dependencies fail.

I have installed the library dependencies via npm, as well as any available typescript definition files. While debugging the library functions, I can see that the injected dependencies are 'undefined'. It also appears that the 'require' keyword is undefined.

I am using `import * as xyz from 'library'` syntax, which is working in that it is loading the library itself. Just not the dependencies.

The crux of the issue seems to be the imported javascript module uses requirejs for dependency management. All of those dependencies are returned as null. How can we resolve those dependencies and make this library work?

Answer (score 0):

You can import any library
e.g Very popular lodash

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Use in your component

```
filter(){
  return _.filter(array, callback)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This part is working, however it appears as though nested requirejs dependencies are not being resolved. Say 'lodash' depends on 'moment' with `require('moment')`, lodash is loaded but any functions requiring moment will not function.